# d3, aligning text to centroid angle

Tags: d3.js

Any idea why the following function does not align the current datum to the angle of the centroid?

```
g.append("svg:text") //append an element with the name "text"
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")" + "rotate(" + (270 + d.startAngle + (d.startAngle - d.endAngle)/2) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.word; });
```

Each text by default is supposed to be at 90 degrees, so I rotate 270 to align to the y axis and then add the startAngle of the current datum to reach its part in the pie chart and then add (d.startAngle - d.endAngle)/2 to reach the angle of the centroid which is arc.centroid(d) . Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with the various rotations, but these will operate on the translated coordinate system, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I am trying to put labels on a pie chart and align each respective label with the line that connects the center of the circle (of the pie chart) to the centroid of each slice of the pie chart.

Comment: `rotate()` takes two additional arguments -- the x and y of the coordinate you want to rotate about. It should work if you set that to the centroid of the arc.

Comment: It didn't work. Setting additional arguments to the centroid of the arc miraculously placed everything in the center of the pie chart! I didn't bother much to find the possible flaw/mistake because I found the solution (see my answer below). Thank you my friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found ( http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2295263 ) :

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")" + "rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
```

where

```
function angle(d) {
  var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
  return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
}
```

computes the angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.